# How to make gradle and PyDev/jython work together?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, pydev, jython, pythonpath

As a small exercise I want to convert a simple `libgdx` application to `jython`. While rewriting the code of the generic empty project is straightforward, manually including all the `jar`-dependencies from the Java buildpath's gradle dependencies is cumbersome (and prone to inconsistency due to the probably changing hashes on updates). Therefore my question, is there any simple way to add the gradle-dependencies to the `PYTHONPATH` in eclipse or to tell gradle to use jython?

I'm using the gradle plugin from http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/TOOLS/gradle/nightly in Eclipse Kepler, if that matters.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15583726/321973

Comment: Sorry, I can't solve your problem but I am delighted to hear that you have managed to get Jython + Gradle + Eclipse working together.  Could you possibly explain how you have done this? I have pulled in the Jython-Gradle plugin at https://github.com/rzabini/gradle-jython but can't get it to import any Java dependency .jars (see recent Issue there opened by me).  Maybe you might be able to email brief instructions?

Comment: @mikerodent I'm afraid three years and two Linux/Windows re-installations later I'm afraid I don't remember m-/ But I think that was my very problem, I used gradle from the command line and then added gradle's download path manually... I'd try it with PyCharm these days instead, maybe you're more lucky there